# define moretexcs (listings)

Tags: listings

I want to define `moretexcs` lists outside of a `lstdefinestyle` macro because I want to load these definitions from a separate tex file. However inside `lstset` `moretexcs` is ignored:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}    
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{lstStyleLaTeX}{%
   ,language = [LaTeX]TeX%
   % ,moretexcs={abc},
   ,keywordstyle=\color{red}
}
\lstset{%
   language=[LaTeX]TeX,
   moretexcs={abc},
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=lstStyleLaTeX]
\abc{content}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: According to the [`listings` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) (section **4.18 Language definitions**, p 42), "If used ‘standalone’ outside a language deﬁnition, the key might work only after selecting a nonempty language (and switching back to the empty language if necessary)." So, perhaps you need `language=[LaTeX]TeX` as part of `\lstset`, and `lanuage={}` afterwards...

Comment: With your changes it does not give an error, but it simply has no effect.

Comment: Why not say `\lstset{style=lstStyleLaTeX, moretexcs={abc}}` and omit the `[style=lstStyleLaTeX]` argument later?

Comment: I changes styles in my document quite often because I use not only LaTeX as a language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following example defines macro `\addmoretexcs`. The optional argument specifies the dialect (default is `common`). The language is loaded if it is not yet available. Then the language definition, internally stored in `\lstlang@<language>$<dialect>`, is extended by setting the additional `moretexcs` list:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{lstStyleLaTeX}{%
   ,language = [LaTeX]TeX%
    % ,moretexcs={abc},
   ,keywordstyle=\color{red}
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\addmoretexcs}[2][common]{%
  \lowercase{\@ifundefined{lstlang@tex$#1}}{%
    \lstloadlanguages{[#1]TeX}%
  }{}%
  \lowercase{\expandafter\g@addto@macro\csname lstlang@tex$#1\endcsname}{%
    \lstset{moretexcs={#2}}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\addmoretexcs[LaTeX]{abc}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=lstStyleLaTeX]
\abc{content}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks very much. Now I can move all commands to a separate file that can be shared between different documents.