# Error related to \spacefactor using 3rd-party macro \addmoretexcs

Tags: errors, listings

I am using the command `\addmoretexcs` for listings, which has its origin [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84207/define-moretexcs-listings).
With the update to TeX Live 2014 (and probably an update to `listings`), the following code returns an error:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{ltxcmds}
\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\IfPackageLoaded}[2]{\ltx@ifpackageloaded{#1}{#2}{}}
\makeatother


\IfPackageLoaded{listings}{%

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\addmoretexcs}[2][common]{%
  \lowercase{\@ifundefined{lstlang@tex$#1}}{%
    \lstloadlanguages{[#1]TeX}%
  }{}%
  \lowercase{\expandafter\g@addto@macro\csname lstlang@tex$#1\endcsname}{%
    \lstset{moretexcs={#2}}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

}% End of \IfPackageLoaded

\addmoretexcs[LaTeX]{setlength}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

The error in question is

```
! You can't use `\spacefactor' in vertical mode.
\@->\spacefactor 
\@m 
l.23 \addmoretexcs[LaTeX]{setlength}
```

Note that, if I substitute `\IfPackageLoaded` with `ltx@ifpackageloaded`, the error disappears. This, however, is not a solution.

The actual error is likely inside the packages; I cannot debug this any further.
Any hints about the origin of this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I doubt the code worked before updating to TeX Live 2014, because it would have been wrong in any case. With

```
\IfPackageLoaded{listings}{%

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\addmoretexcs}[2][common]{%
  \lowercase{\@ifundefined{lstlang@tex$#1}}{%
    \lstloadlanguages{[#1]TeX}%
  }{}%
  \lowercase{\expandafter\g@addto@macro\csname lstlang@tex$#1\endcsname}{%
    \lstset{moretexcs={#2}}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

}% End of \IfPackageLoaded
```

the replacement text of `\addmoretexcs` (actually of an inner macro due to the fact your command has an optional argument) consists of the following tokens (• is used to separate tokens, for clarity)

```
\lowercase • { • \@ • i • f • u • ...
```

because the text given as argument to `\IfPackageLoaded` is already tokenized and TeX *doesn't* execute `\makeatletter` when absorbing this argument.

Correct code:

```
\makeatletter
\IfPackageLoaded{listings}{%
  \newcommand*{\addmoretexcs}[2][common]{%
    \lowercase{\@ifundefined{lstlang@tex$#1}}{%
      \lstloadlanguages{[#1]TeX}%
    }{}%
    \lowercase{\expandafter\g@addto@macro\csname lstlang@tex$#1\endcsname}{%
      \lstset{moretexcs={#2}}%
    }%
  }%
}% End of \IfPackageLoaded
\makeatother
```

Now, when the argument is absorbed, `\@ifundefined` is tokenized as a single token, not twelve.

---

### Some more words

The original code may appear to work if it is included in a `.sty` file, because these files are read in with an implicit `\makeatletter` declaration at the beginning and an implicit `\makeatother` at the end (more precisely, the category code of `@` is restored to the value it had at the moment the `.sty` file was opened).

As a general rule, `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` should never appear in `.sty` files (except when belonging to the replacement text of some macro, which is not the case here). Your usage of `\makeatother` in the second argument of `\IfPackageLoaded` would be wrong in a `.sty` file, because it would change the category code of `@` from that point on in case `listings` has already been loaded.

So, if you are going to use the previous code in a `.sty` file, ***remove*** the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` declarations.

Comment: Indeed, this solved it. However I can confirm that it worked before and also worked for about 3000 other people that downloaded my template.

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech Probably none of them loaded `listings`. Of course, I tried your example with TL 2012 and TL 2013, obviously receiving the same ``You can't use `\spacefactor' in vertical mode`` error in both cases.

Comment: My template loads about 100 packages, and listings is always loaded. Even if someone would disable it in the preamble, a package from myself loads it, so it would be loaded in any case. The code is not in a sty file. I must admit, that I did not test the MWE in TeX Live 2013, but the error first appeared in my template in 2014 and does not (in my full template) in 2013.

Comment: Yes! Thank you for pointing-out the `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` problems with `.sty` files.